# TensorFlow 2.0 dataset.__iter__() is only supported when eager execution is enabled

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

I'm using the following custom training code in TensorFlow 2:

```
def parse_function(filename, filename2):
    image = read_image(fn)
    def ret1(): return image, read_image(fn2), 0
    def ret2(): return image, preprocess(image), 1
    return tf.case({tf.less(tf.random.uniform([1])[0], tf.constant(0.5)): ret2}, default=ret1)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train,shuffled_train))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(train))
dataset = dataset.map(parse_function, num_parallel_calls=4)
dataset = dataset.batch(1)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=4)

@tf.function
def train(model, dataset, optimizer):
    for x1, x2, y in enumerate(dataset):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            left, right = model([x1, x2])
            loss = contrastive_loss(left, right, tf.cast(y, tf.float32))
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))

siamese_net.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=1e-3))
train(siamese_net, dataset, tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=1e-3))
```

This code gives me the error:

```
dataset.__iter__() is only supported when eager execution is enabled.
```

However, it's in TensorFlow 2.0 so eager is enabled by default.
`tf.executing_eagerly()` also returns 'True'.

Comment: I think you're using the wrong order in this line `for x1, x2, y in enumerate(dataset):` enumerate iterator comes first, so in your case it should be y, x1, x2, 
`left, right = model([x1, x2])`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your change. x1, x2, and y are two images and a label returned by the dataset. I used this as a reference: 
https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/keras/training_and_evaluation#using_the_gradienttape_a_first_end-to-end_example

I also added the parse_function

Comment: insert `print(x1)` right after `for x1, x2, y in enumerate(dataset):` You'll get 0 instead of actual value from dataset. In this case x1 is not value, it's an enumerate counter

Comment: Okay two problems here. You are correct with the enumeration. It needs to be:
for step, (x1, x2, y) in enumerate(dataset).
Secondly, I have to remove the line @tf.function for some reason. I'm not sure why this can't be here since it's used a lot in the documentation examples I found but in this case it breaks the dataset iteration. It doesn't work at all with this line and just throws that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by changing the train function to the following:

```
def train(model, dataset, optimizer):
    for step, (x1, x2, y) in enumerate(dataset):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            left, right = model([x1, x2])
            loss = contrastive_loss(left, right, tf.cast(y, tf.float32))
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
```

The two changes are removing the @tf.function and fixing the enumeration.

Comment: Perhaps @tf.function would work without enumerating the dataset

Answer (score 19):

I fixed it by enabling eager execution after importing tensorflow:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()
```

Reference: [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager)

Comment: Note that you should enable it at the beginning of the program

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, this code was already executing eagerly as it was TF2 and tf.executing_eagerly() returned True. The documentation link you posted confirms this. It's possible this would help with another version of tensorflow though. My fix below ended up working for me.

Comment: @emrepun but what if I want to iterate over dataset **not** in eager mode?

Comment: I believe the error indicates that such a thing is not possible without the eager mode. Meaning, we cannot iterate with `__iter__()`  but perhaps there is another solution when the eager mode is disabled. Which unfortunately I don't know how. @404pio

Answer (score 4):

In case you are using Jupyter notebook after

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()
```

You need to restart the kernel and it works