# How to fix "RuntimeError: dataset.__iter__() is only supported when eager execution is enabled."

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to batch the input data, but the error occurs. How do I adjust my code?

```
def input_fn(data,batch_size): 

    Continuous_cols = {k: tf.constant(data[k].values) for k in Columns}

    label = tf.constant(data[Label].values)

    dataset = 
    tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(Continuous_cols.items()), label)) 
    dataset = 
    dataset.batch(batch_size)

    return dataset
```

Comment: Take a look at the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56736763/8447312

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your **runtime type as TPU in Google Colab**.

Comment: While this might answer the question, providing details as to how to reached the conclusion and your thought process will surely help the fellow asker. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)