# RuntimeError: __iter__() is only supported inside of tf.function or when eager execution is enabled

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I am new to tensorflow and trying to learn it. Trying to run an estimator LinearClassifier in Tensorflow 2.2.0.

1. Imported all the modules and read in tfRecords

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.version.VERSION)
import os

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
print (tf.executing_eagerly())
tf.executing_eagerly()
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()

path = 'train.tfrecord'
filenames = [(path + "/" + name) for name in os.listdir(path) if name.startswith("part")]
print (filenames)
```

2. Define the parse function

```
def _parse_function(example_proto):
    features = {
        'Age': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'EstimatedSalary': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'Purchased': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
    }
    tf_records = tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, features)
    features_dict = {
        'Age': tf_records['Age'],
        'EstimatedSalary': tf_records['EstimatedSalary']
    }
    return features_dict, tf_records['Purchased']
```

3. Define the input function to pass in the estimator

```
def input_fn():
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames = filenames)
    
    dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
    iterator = iter(dataset)
    next_element = iterator.get_next()
    return next_element
```

4. Initializing estimator

```
feature_columns = [
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column('Age'),
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column('EstimatedSalary')
]

estimator = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns = feature_columns)
estimator.train(
    input_fn = input_fn
)
```

Running the following code gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "linear_classification.py", line 42, in <module>
    input_fn = input_fn
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 349, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1182, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1208, in _train_model_default
    self._get_features_and_labels_from_input_fn(input_fn, ModeKeys.TRAIN))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1044, in _get_features_and_labels_from_input_fn
    self._call_input_fn(input_fn, mode))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1137, in _call_input_fn
    return input_fn(**kwargs)
  File "linear_classification.py", line 31, in input_fn
    iterator = iter(dataset)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 406, in __iter__
    raise RuntimeError("__iter__() is only supported inside of tf.function "
RuntimeError: __iter__() is only supported inside of tf.function or when eager execution is enabled.
```

Things I tried:

1. forcing eager execution (even tho in tf 2 it is done by default).
2. Trying to search existing StackOverflow: [TensorFlow 2.0 dataset.__iter__() is only supported when eager execution is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55576133/tensorflow-2-0-dataset-iter-is-only-supported-when-eager-execution-is-enab/56736763#56736763)
3. Put print statements in actual tf source code to understand why **context.executing_eagerly()** is setting to False. The **default_execution_mode** in context.py is initialized by EAGER_MODE, so I am confused to why it becomes False

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py
```

This is my first StackOverflow question, so please excuse if I have not followed any guidelines or rules. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I figured out the issue is. As the error states `RuntimeError: __iter__() is only supported inside of tf.function or when eager execution is enabled`. I put the `@tf.function` above my `input_fn()`. So now my `input_fn()` looks like:

```
@tf.function
def input_fn():
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames = filenames)
    
    dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
    iterator = iter(dataset)
    next_element = iterator.get_next()
    return next_element
```

I was able to track the issue by reading the TensorFlow documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/effective_tf2